# 2 different sheets with their own data source

Tags: tableau-desktop

In Tableau Desktop, does anyone know how to switch between 2 data sources in 2 different work sheets?

I created 2 data sources and 2 sheets.

But if I try to assign one sheet a different data source, it changes it for both.

Is there a trick to doing this?

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is click on the data source you want to use on the sheet and add a field from that data source to the sheet. If you don't add a field to the sheet, it doesn't keep the association to that selected data source.

So, for example, say you have 2 data sources in the data source pane. Go to Sheet 1. Click on data source 1. It will display the fields from that data source in the Tables pane.

[image: pic1]

Add one of the fields from data source 1 to Sheet 1. This associates that sheet with data source 1.

Then go to Sheet 2. By default, it's showing the fields from data source 1. To change it to data source 2, just click on that second data source.

[image: pic2]

Then add a field from data source 2 to Sheet 2. Sheet 2 is now using data source 2.

If you go back to Sheet 1, you'll see it's still using data source 1.